# W3C Validator Error

Tags: asp.net, html, image, xhtml, w3c-validation

When I use W3c validater for checking my site it shows

**"required attribute "alt" not specified"**   and also

**" The attribute given above is required for an element that you've used, but you have omitted it. For instance, in most HTML and XHTML document types the "type" attribute is required on the "script" element and the "alt" attribute is required for the "img" element. Typical values for type are type="text/css" for  and type="text/javascript" for . "**

How can I solve this issue?

Screenshot:

[image]

This is my coding:

```
protected string GetImageStyle(ImageStub image)
    {
        if (!image.ImageID.IsNull)
        {
            image = image.ScaleOptimalWidth(75, 75);
            return String.Format("width:75px;height:75px;align='left';-moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px;border-radius: 6px; padding-left: 2px;alt='img';");
        }

        return "width:75px;height:75px;align='left';alt='img'";
    }
```

Comment: Give us a fiddle to look at what your code currently is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `alt` attribute to your `<img />` tags.

Comment: For a more extensive explanation, see [WCAG 2: Using alt attributes on img elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H37)

Comment: @Sujanth according to screenshot you have put ALT in STYLES attribute, when it should be a separate attribute

Comment: @Sujanth You have this <img styles="width:75px;alt='img'" /> when it should be <img styles="width:75px" alt="img" />

Comment: `"img"` is certainly not useful alternative content. Perhaps the validator is now smart enough to recognize that. If you're going to add meaningless alternative text just to get a validator badge, don't bother. I suspect the issue though is that something in your pipeline is HTML encoding the quotes and so the validator is not recognizing the bogus alternative text.